# awk alpha regular expression improvement

Tags: regex, awk

I've a text file that has alpha lines. Some of the alpha lines start with 'Narrated' and needs to be processed differently from all other alpha lines. Below is the test data:

```
This is my article
<img src="">
<a href="">
New magazine
Narrated by abc
<a href="">
Is this a new paper?
<img src="">
<a href="link1">
<a href="link2">
That is an old journal
<img src="">
<a href="">
A fine book!
<img src="">
<a href="">
Yes, this is some book.
Narrated by xyz
<img src="">
<a href="">
```

My current script looks like this:

```
BEGIN  {
    title  = "^[A-Z].*"
    narrated  = "to be defined"
    image = "^<img.*"
    links = "^<a.*"
}

$0 ~ title {
    pos = index($0, "Narrated"); # check if the line contains narrated
    if (pos == 0) {
            print $0; #print other line
    } else {
            print $0; #print narrated line
    }
}
$0 ~ img {
    # do processing
}
$0 ~ link {
    # do processing
}
```

I want to define the "**narrated**" regular expression and improve the "*title*" regular expression. Thanks for help!

The input is a series of data sets that has optional and mandatory items. Some of the items can be repeated. Each set will have following items in below order:
1) description of the item (mandatory)
2) narrated by (optional)
3)  link description  (one or more links per set. mandatory)

Additional info about the data set
a) All items of the set are separated by new lines
b) Last item of the set has ']' as the last character i.e. ]
c) Raw file has other data issues which are not mentioned here (e.g.

What should be RS and FS for this data set?

The expected output is a json array that is produced by parsing the input file and combining the elements based upon other characteristics that are embedded within the data. All related elements occur in sequence so line-by-line processing of the 'processed data file - not raw data file' with awk works as a solution for this problem. Raw file processing by awk will probably work as well but I've not given it a shot as it contains data elements that need to be discarded anyway and required data elements are surrounded by other text elements.

Answer (score 2):

To handle `narrated` lines, just do:

```
/^Narrated/ {do some thing}
```

or

```
$1=="Narrated" {do some thing}
```

`do some thing` will only be run if line starts with `Narrated`
I do not see why you should use regular expression here.

Title lines could be:

```
/^This is/ {do some thing}
```

Pleas post expected output of your code.

Comment: Thanks Jotne. The "This is ..." is for example purposes. It could be any other alpha string but it will NEVER start with 'Narrated'. So there are lines starting with 'Narrated' and there are lines starting with any other alpha string. I updated the example data file.

Comment: @Lafani It then seems for me that you have two types of line `Narrated ` that you get like this `/^Narrated/` than you have the `book` line that you get by this `/book$/` (book at end of line).

Comment: @Lafani  If you have only two types of data, do `/^Narrated/` for `Narrated` lines and `!/^Narrated/` for all other.  Also post what it the expected output of this.

Comment: I've provided more info about input and output